# how do you add more than one peice of content to a variable in php

Tags: php

I have two variables with an error message if it is not the same content, how do I make it so that the `$antispam_answer` variable has two possible answers lets say `test` and `test1`

I have my php below

```
$antispam_answer = "test";
$antispam = "test1";

if($antispam <> $antispam_answer) {
$error_message .= 'The anti-spam you entered is not correct.<br />';
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "has two possible answers"?  It's not clear to me what you're trying to do.  Do you mean that you want to have a value in one variable and an *array* in another, and check if that value is in that array?

Comment: @David so that it will be like if `$antispam` is `test` or `test1`

Comment: weird CAPTCHA to have more than one option, bad to have hard coded fixed options(s) and you will never actually do better than using reCAPTCHA

Comment: @IdontDownVote services change over time.  I personally can't stand reCAPTCHA from a usability perspective.  Why not roll your own?  I'm reading this as an antispam multi-choice like: 'Pick a fish from the following: cod, tuna, leopard, orangutan'.

Comment: have you used the  invisible reCAPTCHA @Progrock?

Comment: @Progrock reCAPTCHA has got to be one of the easiest ones to use now.  Most the time, all you have to do is check a box.   Why not roll your own?  Because plugging in recaptcha takes a few minutes and is well supported by Google.  I think the same argument exists for why use libraries?

Comment: @Devon, I understand the convenience, but interfacing with a third party service, may not be to everyone's taste.

Comment: @Progrock rather than having a conversation, could you please help me find a solution as the array that Devon said didn't work

Comment: @IdontDownVote also to you

Comment: @Devon and to you

Comment: @DasShield The solution will definitely work if the values are set properly.  Like I suggested before, you need to learn how to debug your code.  Open up a php interactive console and test in_array yourself.

Answer (score 1):

```
// An array of the possible answers
$antispam_possibilities = ['test', 'test1'];

// Check that the value of $antispam_answer is not in the array $antispam_possibilities
if(!in_array($antispam_answer, $antispam_possibilities)) {
    $error_message .= 'The anti-spam you entered is not correct.<br />';
}
```

Comment: for some reason this isn't working for either, it always says The anti-spam you entered is not correct.

Comment: Then the value of $antispam_answer likely isn't what you expect.  This is the power of a debugger.  I suggest you read up on how to debug PHP code.

Comment: @DasShield how is `$antispam_answer` being populated

Comment: @IdontDownVote it is linked to an html, I just edited it when I posted it

Comment: @Devon why does this not just work?   `if($antispam <> $antispam_answer or $antispam <> $antispam_answer2) {
    $error_message .= 'The anti-spam you entered is not correct.<br />';
  }`

Comment: @DasShield this could be a logic error do you want an and?  With an or, either side evaluating to true will evaluate the whole statement to true.

Answer (score 0):

Fleshed out version of Devon's answer, with example inputs.

```
<?php
function antispam_validate($answer)
{
    $antispam =
    [
        'question' => 'Which of the following is human clothing?',
        'choices'  => [0=>'tie', 1=>'shoe', 2=>'house', 3=>'crisps'],
        'answers'  => [0, 1]
    ];

    $is_valid_choice = array_key_exists($answer, $antispam['choices']);
    if(!$is_valid_choice)
        throw new Exception('Invalid choice for answer.');

    $is_correct = in_array($answer, $antispam['answers']);

    return $is_correct;
}
var_dump(antispam_validate(1));
var_dump(antispam_validate(2));
```

Output:

```
bool(true)
bool(false)
```